# What happens if I wrote my Own method in Servlet?

Tags: servlets, methods

What will happen if I write my own method inside the body of a servlet? Does the servlet container take care of it? If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Could you post a code sample? Or explain what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @ JB Niaet :This question asked in an interview . I answered that we can write but container don't take care of that method as per servlet life cycle. I want to check this answer is correct or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the servlet dont supports Custom Http methods to be called by browser.

Please read the chapter 2 of servlet 2.5 specification about the supported methods

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/

Answer (score 1):

Yes Servlet Container supports Custom Http methods. When the any method is called, the container will call service() method. And it the HttpServlet.service() method which returns HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED status code for http methods other than standard Http methods like GET, POST, etc.

If you want to have custom http methods. Override the service() method, get the method using HttpServletRequest.getMethod(), and invoke your custom method.

For Ex,

```
 public class CustomMethodServlet extends HttpServlet{


public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {\
   if(request.getMethod().equals("foo")){
   //invoke your custom method
     doFoo(request,response);
   }else {
      super.service(request, response);
   }

}
public void doFoo(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   //implement your custom method
}
```

}

The above method in Servlet can be invoked using `foo` http method.

Comment: Sorry i was mistaken. I was thinking Servlet containers calls custom http methods by default. But one can write custom http method, override service() method and using HttpServletRequest.getMethod() invoke the custom method using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you means a JSP page and not a servlet. A servlet is a Java class and has no body. A servlet has a service method and methods and some others. Java does not support that you write a method inside another.

Comment: OP seems to be more talking about [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), not about Java methods.